# How can create a nested d.ts file?

Tags: typescript, import, namespaces, export, declare

I'm building a module that can be used both in JS & TS.
As far as I know, when create a module in JS, create a separate `d.ts` file.(Of course can make using TS and compile to JS). Anyway I chose to make `d.ts` file.

For example.

```
// common.d.ts

declare namespace common {
  export const method: string => string;
}
export = common;
```

Next,

```
// utils.d.ts
import * as u from './common';
declare namespace utils {
  export const common: u // Causing an error.
}
export = utils;
```

And I got this error: `The namespace 'u' can not be used as a format.`
I want to write this to unify import addresses.

```
import { common as u } from '/utils';
u.method('Any params');
```

I guess, maybe I can get the declarations from the `t.ds` file and assign them. But I do not know how. Anybody help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `export const common: u` with `export const common = u` will remove the error but will copy only the value meaning of `u`; interfaces and type aliases defined in `common.d.ts` won't be accessible via this `common` constant.  `export import common = u` is better: it copies all meanings.  But most people would consider it even better to remove the pointless combination of a namespace and an export assignment and move the individual exports from the namespace to the top level of the module; then you can use ECMAScript `export as` syntax instead of a TypeScript alias.

```
// common.d.ts
export const method: string => string;

// utils.d.ts
import * as u from './common';
export { u as common };
```